# How to center div without centering list items

Tags: css

Design:
[image]

I would like to have list of items in 4 columns. I will put that block on a separate row on a page. I would like to see div class **condition-box-list** centered but list item should be aligned left. I also like to see a separator line between the columns.

HTML:

```
<div class ="condition-box-list">

<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.condition-box-list{text-align:center}
```

How it looks now:
[image]

How can I place the div class **condition-box-list** in center while list-items are aligned left? Also how to put the line to separate the columns?

---

Update.

It seems to me easy but it is being complicated. 
[image]

Comment: to center a div you can use margin auto, flexbox methods and various other methods.

Comment: @learn4ever If my or any of the solution solved your query, it'd be appreciated to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you're making use of **bootstrap** add "`row`" class to your parent container (*condition-box-list*). The columns class **always** need to be wrapped in the parent container having class row in bootstrap.

- For smaller displays to make it still responsive in a row fashion you could make use of `display:flex` *(make sure then that **col-sm-4** & **col-xs-12** will have lost their effect)* and add a **right border to the columns** as demonstrated in the CSS.

```css
.condition-box-list{
display:flex;
}
.condition-box-list>*{
border-right:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class ="condition-box-list row">

<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

**Second solution:**
If you do not want them to take the span of the entire row (12 bootstrap grid columns) then don't make use of col-* or rows. Just use **flexbox**:

```css
.condition-box-list{
display:flex;
justify-content: center; /*Aligns contents horizontally */
text-align:left;
width:100%;
}
.condition-box-list>*{
border-right:2px solid black;
width:20%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class ="condition-box-list">

<div class="whyus-box">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="whyus-box">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item one</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> two </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> item three</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width you want, then use `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Else, you can use flexbox. Check this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. The property for you here is justify-content.

Answer (score 0):

you can center a div with:

```
   yourdiv {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this should help:

```
.whyus-box {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.condition-box-list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.condition-box-list li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

I didn't know your entire CSS, so I made up my own. But the idea is simple:
Make the text inside the li left-aligned and the ul should be inline-blocks and center-aligned (by setting the text-align: center on their parent).

Hope this helps.